# MySQL before insert trigger using foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, dml

say I have table A and table B, Where the primary key of table A is the foreign key of table B. Table A is an enumeration class with a couple of possible values. However, filling the columns of table B depend on the value of the foreign key coming from table A. For example, if the foreign key is "`x`" then only columns 1,3,5 get filled. If the foreign key is instead "`y`" then the columns that get filled are 2,4. The columns are within table B. These columns that weren't filled will have NULL values. What would be the syntax for this using triggers? Here is an example of what each table might look like.

Table A:

```
+-------+
| Type  | 
+-------+
| x     |  
| y     |  
+-------+
```

The primary key here is `Type`

table B:

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+------+---------+ 
| Id    | col1        | col2 | col3| col4    | col5 |Type     | 
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+ 
| 12    | val1        | NULL | val3| NULL    | val5 |   x     | 
| 54    | NULL        | val2 |NULL | val4    | NULL |    y    | 
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

where `Type` is the foreign key.

an example `insert` statement:

`INSERT INTO B VALUES('13','val1', 'val2 ', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5','x')`

The primary key of table B would be `Id` and this value is always unique.

Comment: Could explain this please a little more. When you add a row to Table b and in the foreign key is the value x then there has to be a x also in table a in **one** column that is referenced. And where in that scenario come the other columns and from with table are they. Instead of trying to explain it show us tables and the insert and the says i want xyz

Comment: @nbk unfortunately I do not have tables with data yet but I made some mock tables with sample data.

Comment: It is better if you have a second table B because trigger don't allow manipulation of the same table as the one which fired the trigger. the you take every new.column and build your own table b1 with two new rows.